# Selenium does not find element using By.CLASS_NAME and raises NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm using the following code to identify the Next button, but Selenium does not find it

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)

python_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "nav next rndBtn ui_button primary taLnk")
python_button.click()
```

The error is the following:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .nav next rndBtn ui_button primary taLnk
```

Snapshot of the HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the ***clickable*** element further to invoke click on it you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.nav.next.rndBtn.ui_button.primary.taLnk[data-page-number][onclick*='STANDARD_PAGINATION']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='nav next rndBtn ui_button primary taLnk'][@data-page-number and contains(@onclick, 'STANDARD_PAGINATION')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [***NoSuchElementException***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)

Comment: it does not work. I does not find the element again. please see my updated post, I have added the waittime as well.

Comment: _I have added the waittime as well_: Adding _`implicitly_wait()`_ may not be of any help. Just copy paste the line of code from the answer and update me the result.

Comment: so if I use XPATH it does not find the element. if I use CSS_SELECTOR it does not give any error, but it does not click the actual button on the webpage.

Comment: Did you happen to check the linked reference discussions, incase your usecase isn't generic and needs some more tweaks?

Comment: Thanks. Now it works to click on the button, but I cannot get the new page_source. The link in Tripadvisor does not update btw. After `click()` I run again `s_city = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")`

Comment: Glad to be able to help you. _"I cannot get the new page_source"_ sounds to be a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirements.